# MVC Validation for ajax modal, controller return view without layout, i want to see msg-errors in modal

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, asp.net-ajax

i have 'ajax modal' on my MVC webapp, on that modal i input and submit some data, and want to validate that input. I know how it normaly works, but with ajax modal, there is problem. In case when ModelState is not valid, i want to see modal with error mesages, not view without layout like i have now.

I return:

```
  return View("UrediUtakmicu", _utakmica);
```

"UrediUtakmicu" is view where we input and submit data, "_utakmica" is ViewModel that i return to edit invalid data. As i say, i see error-msg in view without layout, what shoud i do to se that in modal window.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your page load script. Replace the YourInformationalMessage with the property in your model that has the message.

```html
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                .html(Model.YourInformationalMessage)
                .dialog({
                         modal: true,
                         title: '',
                         autoOpen: true,
                         width: "auto",
                         resizable: false,
                         buttons: { Ok: function () { $(this).remove(); }}
                          });
```